# Code design suggestions for Unity event pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, callback

I'm working with Unity C# for my personal project.

I have seperated Model and View. I want View to be automatically updated when somethings in model change.

So I made an Action object, and added all view-updating functions to it.

The thing is, there is super many fields in model. Adding the event to these fields would be really tedious job, and moreover, a single variable change will cause the whole UI to be updated, which may be a huge waste of perfomance.

But adding individual Action object to each of these fields would be much more tedious job.

All I want is that View is updated when Model is changed, and I think this event pattern is the best choice for my situation.

Are there any suggestions for my code design?

Comment: I would not use events to tell the view to update when the model changes.

Comment: Show us your code and your attempt please.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a [great article](https://unity3d.com/how-to/architect-with-scriptable-objects) on using ScriptableObjects to handle events like this. That being said, Unity uses an Entity-Component pattern, and retrofitting MVC pattern contradicts some of the optimizations that EC and Unity provide.

Comment: So you're saying that, sticking on MVC pattern with Unity is not a good idea?

Comment: @MyBug18 correct. What is the problem you're trying to solve by using MVC?

Comment: Actually I'm not that familiar with Unity. I thought that having a huge Game class will make me manage the code more easily, but now I'm quite stuck with UI handling. I've just took a quick look about Scriptable Objects, but I see no difference between traditional event and SO. It also seems like I have to make super many SO for observing many fields. What's the advantage of using SO over just events?

Comment: ScriptableObjects are usable by a game designer or non-technical resource to configure a game. They are drag/droppable using the interface/inspectors for game objects. This allows coders to focus on tactical solutions, and game designers focus on strategic ones. It allows for very strict S.O.L.I.D. principles.